# When to use what type of table relations in SQL databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

How do you determine what type of table relations to use for different data throughout the database?  When is the database big enough to warrant one method over the other?

This can be better explained with an example.  Say you have some automotive test data you want to log.  You'll have information such as model year and model

**Example 1 - one table**

```
entryID | modelYear | model
   1    |   2011    | Fusion
   2    |   2012    | Focus
   3    |   2013    | Explorer
   4    |   2011    | Focus
```

If we want to get all of the Focus entries, you can pull data direct from this main table using where model="Focus"

**Example 2 - two tables with number index in main table**

```
main_table
entryID | modelYear | model
   1    |   2011    |   1
   2    |   2012    |   2
   3    |   2013    |   3
   4    |   2011    |   2

model_lookup_table
modelID | model
   1    | Fusion
   2    | Focus
   3    | Explorer
```

In this case, you'll have to look up based on the model column in main, compare against modelID in the model_lookup_table and join those together.

**Example 3 - two tables with entry index kept in model_lookup table**

```
main_table
entryID | modelYear
   1    |   2011    
   2    |   2012    
   3    |   2013    

model_lookup_table
modelID | entryID | model
   1    |    1    | Fusion
   2    |    2    | Focus
   3    |    3    | Explorer
   4    |    1    | Focus
```

In this case, you'll be comparing main_table.entryID and model_lookup_table.entryID to pull a final table.  Note that the number of main table entries is kept to 3 instead of 4.

---

My thoughts:

Example 1 - Quick and dirty, but okay for small databases

Example 2 - Proper relational database for columns with single entries

Example 3 - Proper relational database for columns with multiple values relating to another column and limits the number of entries in the "main table"

Am I on the right track?

Comment: example 2 seems correct to me, not sure what you're showing with example 3, it doesn't make much sense to me. With model_lookup_table you seem to be trying to create a linking table, so model shouldn't be in there. With example 3, you would have `main` linked to `model_lookup` linked to `model`, but i don't think this is required as you don't have a many to many relationship.

Comment: I think I explained example 3 poorly....  So say you have two model entries with model_year as 2011 (ie. a 2011 focus and 2011 fusion).  Using the style of Example 2, you would have to have a second entry with model_year as 2011 for a total of 4 records in the main table.

With Example 3, your main table would be left at 3 records (2011, 2012, 2013), even though 2011 may have two models associated with it.

Comment: Yes, the third example makes little sense; it appears to possibly be trying to represent a many-to-many relationship where no such relationship is accounted for.

Comment: Updated Examples 1-3 to hopefully make Example 3 a bit more clear as to what I'm after.  Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Another example would be if you're adding test numbers to those vehicles.  What if 2011 Focus has four test numbers associated with it.  Instead of adding four almost identical entries in the main table, you can use the style of Example 3 to associate a single entry in main with the four different test numbers.

Comment: It's not that example 3 was unclear, it just doesn't make any sense to do it that way; what you've done is essentially turned the "main" table into nothing but a year "lookup" table... and end up using an int to point to an int. Edit: I'm not sure what you mean by "test" numbers, but there is nothing in the second example that prevents you from adding an additional field in the main table and having multiple entries with the same (modelYear, model) values. _If you wouldn't want the "main" table to contain such redundancy, then you would add a dependent table for such information._

Comment: Example 3 works exactly the same as example 2, except the year is in a lookup table as opposed to the model. There's nothing special about your "main" table.

Comment: Ahhh @reaanb, explained like that makes sense.  So both would be correct, it's just a matter of context of what to choose.  In the examples above, it obviously makes more sense to use Example 2.  However, if each model_year/model combination has 50 columns associated with it, then it might make more sense to use Example 3 styling.  For example, if you're taking sound data, you'll have columns for RPM, then the sound level at 10 Hz, 20 Hz...... 500 Hz - each having it's own column.

Comment: If you have additional attributes that belong to only the model (or modelYear), then that element is a good choice for a lookup table. Otherwise, all 3 examples have a table that combines model and modelYear, in which the 50 columns can be defined.

Comment: I can't think of any instances where using ex3 would make sense; it is just ex2, but instead of moving the likely-to-repeated string out to and referencing with an int, you're moving a simple int out an referencing it with an int. Assuming ex2 - Attributes that are the same (and always will be) for all instances/years of a model, should be on the model. If it does/will/could vary from year to year, it should be in the "main" table.

Comment: On another note; whenever I hear a large number of columns of similar data suggested, such as your Hz measurements, I find it is often the case that such data should be in its own table, referencing the original table. 
"50 rows referencing" rather than "50 columns"

Comment: @Uueerdo  That makes sense about having it's own table referencing the original table, but at this point, isn't this what ex3 is doing?

Comment: ex3 is just a poor version of ex2. ex3's "main" table is just a "year lookup" table, and it's "model_lookup_table" is the actual "main" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup tables are useful if a domain (e.g. the valid list of models) meets any of the following conditions:

- Expandable (as in values will be added or removed in the future, especially if by users).
- Many possible values, which are difficult to check using row/column constraints (e.g. ENUMs or CHECK constraints).
- Associated attributes or relationships (e.g. a model is available as automatic, manual or both, has regional translations, or is related to a manufacturer). More formally, see the 2nd and 3rd normal forms of database relations.
- Values require relatively large storage space, compared to a surrogate key. Note I'm not advising a surrogate key be used for all lookup tables, a natural key (e.g. a year number) is perfectly fine.
- The representation of values change frequently, e.g. product names that get changed often.

Your example 1 is perfectly valid as it stands, but in a complete database some of the factors above may become important. Based on the criteria above the model probably is a better candidate for a lookup table than the modelYear, but note it's possible to make lookup tables for both if required.